# Android - Textview change color on changing of state

Tags: android, textview

How can I apply color on the various states(focused, pressed, enabled) of the TextView?

I have already referred this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/ColorStateList.html , but do not know how can I apply color state list to the TextView? or is there any other way to do so ?

### Update:

**I want to change the Background color.**

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Create new a new `xml` (in the `drawable` folder). with the color you can specify image for each [event state](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList)
and you can you can set this xml as you background

if your xml is '`res/drawable/abc.xml`' then set background as

```
android:background="@drawable/abc"
```

Edited to add color in state xml
our xml, `res/drawable/abc.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_selected="true"   
    android:drawable="@color/gray" />
</selector>
```

Then declare gray in `your res\values\strings.xml`

```
<color name="gray">#808080</color>
```

Comment: thanx for the support, by your example we can set the drawable background, but how can i set the background color? becoz i have to create 3 different set of images for each drawable ,which i think not good idea, so please

Comment: so how can i set the background color on different state of textview ? is it possible?

Comment: I have edited it to set the background color on different state of textview. Check it now, I hope that was your problem

Answer (score 37):

create xml under res/color dir.

example file name : selector_white_gray.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
          android:color="@color/Gray"/> <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:color="@color/White"/> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

you can add more states. you can use color code like "#ffffff" instead of predefined "@color/White".
Becarefull, use android:color   not   android:drawable. this example changes color of text when pressed on it. set the textColor attribute to selector above.

```
<TextView
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_weight="1"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:textColor="@color/selector_white_gray"
       android:textSize="18sp" 
       android:textStyle="bold" >
</TextView>
```

Comment: I think you meant `@drawable/selector_white_grey` not `@color/selector_white_grey`.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. If i remember correct, code samples are from working code. So it must be color. But you can test it. For now i do not access to my development machine to verify.

Comment: @lschlessinger "@drawable" is often used when defining a states for the background of a view (you might confuse it with that common situation). In this case it is not used for background, but for textColor, so "@color" should be correct.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change color of the text - you create it as an xml in res/color folder ( for example res/color/mycolor.xml
and then in your TextView you assig it  color as  `android:textColor="@color/mycolor"`

For changing background see other answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy. Just intercept desired event and write smth like:

```
TextView textView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.myText);
String s=getString(R.string.myText);
SpannableString ss=new SpannableString(s);
ss.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), 0, s.length(), Spanned.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
textView.setText(ss);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
mMainView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        textView.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);//set the color here
    }

});
```

Comment: Thanks for answering but question is about changing textview background color on changing of state, not about changing text color on clicking it!