# How to change selected text color inTextView?

Tags: android, textview, android-theme

I am using this `android:textIsSelectable="true"` in my TextView for select + copy-paste options and it's working just fine. But I just run into a problem, The selection part appear to be transparent in color. attaching the screenshot for understanding [image]

Now I want to change the color of the selected portion . Is there a way to change the selected portion color.Any help is greatly appreciated.

**Edit**

Ok ,I seems to have find the issue.The issue was because I was not calling super  on `onDraw()` instead I was drawing the text ie `canvas.drawText()` I made a small workaround for it, which is not perfect.Does anyone know how to set the highlight path using `canvas.drawText()` ?

Comment: Did you tried providing a selector drawable as textcolor by setting android:state_focused/android:state_pressed color

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4336218/android-textview-change-color-on-changing-of-state you mean something like this ..? Which is for changing the textcolor right ?

Comment: Yes..2nd answer from that link.

Comment: I dont want the text color to change ... I want something like this http://i.stack.imgur.com/zF9JD.png I want to change the background of selection..